# Determine if the following subset is a subspace of the indicated vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

$W=\{\text {A|A in} M_{22}, \text {A is not invertible}\}$ $\in M_{22}$

Since 2 non-invertible matrix $\in M_{22}$ can be added up to an invertible matrix, it is not closed under addition, therefore it is not a subspace of $M_{22}$.

Comment: Correct. You might even given an explicit example.

Comment: @copper.hat Not “might”, but “should”.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  Here is an example that you may use to be more explicit in your statement that $W$ is not closed under addition:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = I_2 \notin W, $$
but each of the matrices in the sum is an element of $W$. You may be so inclined to check, however, that $W$ *is* closed under scalar multiplication.